# How to identify similar numbers from database before insert

Tags: sql-server, azure, databricks, azure-cognitive-search, azure-cognitive-services

I have a table with 20 million rows of phone numbers, which is synced to azure cognitive search. I need to search before creating a new row. Lets say I have a record with number "1234567890" if a request comes with number "1234567899" or "1234557890", this request is slightly similar to the one which is already in db. Is there any way to do that in MSSQL or Cognitive search or in Azure or any other tool.

I tried with cognitive fuzzy search, but it is not accurate

Comment: What analyzer are you using on the field? And is there any other content within the same field? Or is it just a phone number by itself?

Comment: what is a similar number?   area code 202 is DC/MD while 212 is NY yet they are only one digit off